# Remover último item do jSON com jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Tenho o json messe formato:

```
{
"indice1":['nome1', 'nome2'],
"indice2":['nome1', 'nome2', 'nome3']
}
```

O que quero é quando o usuário clicar no botão de excluir ele exclua o ultimo item do json. No caso do jSON acima ele excluiria o `nome3` e ao clicar novamente excluiria o `nome2`e depois excluiria o `nome1`juntamente com o indice `indice2`(pois iria excluir o ultimo item do jSON e deixa ele vazio entao poderia excluir tb o indice). E assim por diante, sempre excluindo o ultimo item.

Answer (score 1):

Usando a função `.pop()` do `javascript`, e selecionando qual a chave que deve ter o elemento excluído, você consegue. Nesse caso, dessa forma:

**HTML**  para testar

```
<input type="button" value="exclui ultimo do indice 1" data-indice="indice1" />
<input type="button" value="exclui ultimo do indice 2" data-indice="indice2" />
```

**Javascript**

```
var indices = {
    "indice1":['nome1', 'nome2'],
    "indice2":['nome1', 'nome2', 'nome3']
};

$("[data-indice]").on("click", function(event){
    var k = $(this).data("indice");
    // se o índice "k" (equivale a indice1 por exemplo) existir, então
    if (k in indices) {
        // aqui faz o que você precisa, seleciona o indice e apaga o ultimo elemento
        indices[k].pop();
        // aqui a prova que a linha de cima funciona
        alert(indices[k]);
        // aqui uma verificação do total que consta no item, se igual a zero, então excluí o índice
        if (indices[k].length == 0) {
            // tchau índice
            delete indices[k];
        }
    } else {
        alert('o indice ' + k + ' não existe mais!');
    }
});
```

Postei aqui no [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4mLeLnfd/1/) para conferir funcionando.